# Find lines with a phrase and print another section of the line

Tags: python, search, split, text-files, phrase

I am trying to search through a long text file to locate sections where a phrase is located and then print the  phrase in one column and the corresponding data in another in a new text file.

Phrase I am looking for is `"Initialize All"`. The text file will have thousands of lines - the one I am looking for will look something like this:

```
14-09-23 13:47:46.053 -07 000000027 INF: Initialize All start
```

This is where I am at so far
Still trying to print three separate columns: Initialize All, Date, Time

```
with open ('Result.txt', 'w') as wFile:
    with open('Log.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'Initialize All' in line:
                date, time = line.split(" ",2)[:2]
                wFile.write(date)
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this?

Comment: if you know initialize all is in the line why are you trying to print it?

Comment: I will incorporate other phrases as well like "Uninitialize All" Ideally I would create a doc with columns describing the event - "initialize" or "uninitialize" with the date and time

Comment: just set it manually, if `initialize` is in the line use initialize `elif` `uninitialize` is in the line use uninitialize

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Inintialize All' in line:
            # do stuff with line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "14-09-23 13:47:46.053 -07 000000027 INF: Initialize All start"
if "Initialize All" in s: # check for substring
     date, time = s.split(" ",2)[:2] # split on whitespace and get the first two elements
     print date,time

14-09-23 13:47:46.053
```

The `2` in `s.split(" ",2)` means the `maxsplit` is set to `2` so we just split twice other than splitting the whole string, `s.split()[:2]` will also work as it splits on whitespace by default but as we only want the first two substrings  there is no point splitting the whole string.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful - can you explain the use of the 2s? What each represents?

Comment: It is `maxsplit`m it just means split twice other than splitting the whole string, there is no point splitting the whole string as we just want the first two substrings. `s.split()[:2]` will also work as it splits on whitespace by default but as already mentioned no pint splitting the whole string.

Comment: Please consider editing the answer to include this extra information.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `regex`:

```
lines=open('file.txt', 'r').readlines()
[re.search(r'\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}',line).group(0) for line in lines: if 'Inintialize All' in line]
```

Comment: there is absolutely no reason to need a regex

Comment: i wrote it , for handling the exceptions like , bad indentation or maybe there is some extra character in leading of the line or ...